# python wait even with threading

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I everyone and thank you first of all
I'm trying to develop a project for university, I'm using a raspberry pi 3 to create a robot with some features.
Each python file works perfectly.
Now I wanted to put everything together, for example, I tell the rover to follow and it starts following the line on the ground until I say rover stop, and here's the problem when it goes into follow mode it no longer waits for voice commands.
I haven't been able to move forward from this point for a few weeks and the delivery date is approaching quickly.

Rover.py

```
import threading
from Motor import *
from Line_Tracking import *

class Rover:
    def __init__(self):
        self.motor=Motor()
        self.linetrack=Line_Tracking()


    def stopMode(self):
        try:
            self.linetrackRunEv.set()
            self.linetrackRun.join()
            self.motor.setMotorModel(0,0,0,0)
        except:
            pass

     def lt(self):
         self.stopMode()
         self.linetrackRunEv=threading.Event()
         self.linetrackRun=threading.Thread(target=self.linetrack.run, args=(self.linetrackRunEv,))
         self.linetrackRun.start()
         self.line=True
```

Line_Tracking.py

```
from Motor import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import threading

class Line_Tracking:
    def __init__(self):
        self.IR01 = 14
        self.IR02 = 15
        self.IR03 = 23
        self.motor=Motor()
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.IR01,GPIO.IN)
        GPIO.setup(self.IR02,GPIO.IN)
        GPIO.setup(self.IR03,GPIO.IN)

    def run(self, ev):
        self.ev=ev
        while True:
            self.LMR=0x00
            if GPIO.input(self.IR01)==True:
                self.LMR=(self.LMR | 4)
            if GPIO.input(self.IR02)==True:
                self.LMR=(self.LMR | 2)
            if GPIO.input(self.IR03)==True:
                self.LMR=(self.LMR | 1)
            if self.LMR==2:
                self.motor.setMotorModel(800,800,800,800)
            elif self.LMR==4:
                self.motor.setMotorModel(-1500,-1500,2500,2500)
            elif self.LMR==6:
                self.motor.setMotorModel(-2000,-2000,4000,4000)
            elif self.LMR==1:
                self.motor.setMotorModel(2500,2500,-1500,-1500)
            elif self.LMR==3:
                self.motor.setMotorModel(4000,4000,-2000,-2000)
            elif self.LMR==7:
                self.motor.setMotorModel(0,0,0,0)
            if self.ev.is_set():
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

main.py

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import logging
from logging import config
from Rover import *

rover = Rover()

def execCom(com):
    if com == "follow":
        rover.lt()  #<<< -- Once here listening stop
    elif com == "stop":
        rover.stopMode()

...
def listenWithGoogle()
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    listenWithGoogle()
```

Thank you very much

I've already tested it with a finite loop (for) and after the loop it waits again for voice commands, but i really want the voice command to cancel